# Is System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs namespace built-in .NET 5.0?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm trying to migrate the project from .Net Framework 4.5 to .NET 5.0. The  SignedCms class from System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs namespace is used in this project. [It looks like](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.pkcs.signedcms?view=net-5.0) .NET 5.0 includes this namespace. But I receive the error:

```
Error   CS1069  The type name 'SignedCms' could not be found in the namespace 'System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs'. This type has been forwarded to assembly 'System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
```

My question is: Should I install NuGet package for system.security.cryptography.pkcs? Or it is possible to enable this namespace in another way?

Comment: It should be present: see "Applies to" [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.pkcs.signedcms?view=net-5.0)

Comment: @canton7 I thought so but in reality, the error disappeared after the NuGet package installation only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just install the NuGet package and move on.